# React e React-native array.map

Tags: react, react-native

Muitos colaboradores vem me perguntar como realizar um `map` de forma fácil e descomplicado e que sempre que procuram na Internet fica dando a volta ao mundo. mas enfim, vamos lá:

1. eu crio um `state` que nesse exemplo vai ser : `lista : []`
2. eu mando um `setState` após receber os valores que desejo normalmente por axios.
3. apresentar o `state` no render com os valores por variáveis.

Segue exemplo:

```
state = {
   lista : []
}

//fazer o retorno da forma que preferir
this.setstate({lista: resposta.data})

render () {
    return (
        {this.state.lista.map((val)=> ({val.name})
    )
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta!

Comment: essa é a forma de fazer...não tem pra onde correr

Comment: Pergunta sem pé sem cabeça sem corpo, ou seja, não tem como entender!

Comment: Esse é um comentário que muitas pessoas chegam a mim, coloquei aqui exatamente pra minimizar a dúvida da galera, ou seja é mais um desabafo

Comment: [Stackoverflow não é fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum) para fazer desabafos

Comment: [Como perguntar?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, bacana Allan?

Edit: Quase me esqueci de mensionar em qual link me inspirei para te responder. Segue:

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-loop-through-arrays-in-react-3eaa8a14445

Sobre o map, bora lá:

Não existe uma fórmula mágica para uma iteração. Ela tem que ser desenvolvida de acordo com a sua necessidade, sabe?

Criei um exemplo aqui pra você. Bora debugar:

```js
import React from 'react';
import EasyMap from './components/EasyMap';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <EasyMap />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Coloquei acima um exemplo de um App, importando o componente que fará a iteração.

Mas o segredo está no próximo código:

```js
import React from 'react';

const resposta = [
  { id: 35, item: 'jumper', color: 'red', size: 'medium', price: 20 },
  { id: 42, item: 'shirt', color: 'blue', size: 'medium', price: 15 },
  { id: 71, item: 'socks', color: 'black', size: 'all', price: 5 },
];

class EasyMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lista: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setNewData();
  }

  setNewData() {
    this.setState({
      lista: resposta,
    });
  }

  mapReturn(callback) {
    return callback.map(value => {
      return (
        <div key={value.id}>
          <h2>{`Product: ${value.item}`}</h2>
          <p>{`Color: ${value.color}`}</p>
          <p>{`Size: ${value.size}`}</p>
          <p>{`Price: $${value.price}`}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.mapReturn(this.state.lista)}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default EasyMap;
```

1. Criei um componente chamado "EasyMap" que recebe um constructor para tratar o state, e no state criei uma key (Que foi a key que você pediu).
2. Chamei no ComponentDidMount(Que é uma função que faz parte do lifecicle do React, onde ele executa essa função assim que o componente é montado) uma função que modifica o valor do state para um array, que eu criei acima do componente.
3. Criei uma função (mapReturn) que cria uma div para cada objeto dentro do array, onde é passado pra essa div uma key(Necessária para o React gerenciar melhor seus componentes), e nessa div foram passadas várias tags

   com acessos aos valores de cada objeto nesse array. Ou seja: Cada objeto recebe uma div, recebendo sua Key e suas propriedades/values.
4. É renderizada essa função dentro do return do componente, dentro de uma , pois é necessário para que o React receba uma  pai nessa função.

Manda bala. Tmj!